# React Router Equivalent of render props in Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I found this interesting piece of code [(here)](https://medium.com/@mattywilliams/generating-an-automatic-breadcrumb-in-react-router-fed01af1fc3) that generates breadcrumbs together with dynamically rendered routes:

**routes.ts**

```
  { path: "/home", name: "Home", Component: Home },
  { path: "/dashboard", name: "Dashboard", Component: Dashboard },
  { path: "/all-users", name: "All users", Component: AllUsers  },
  { path: "/user/:id", name: "User", Component: User },
  { path: "/all-contracts", name: "All contracts", Component: AllContracts },
  { path: "/login", name: "Login", Component: Login }
];
```

**App.tsx**

```
        <Router>
           <Switch>

                 { routes.map(({ path, Component }, key) => (
                        <Route
                          path={path}
                          key={key}
                          
                          render={ (props:any) => {
                              const crumbs = routes
                                .filter(({ path }) => props.match.path.includes(path))
                                .map(({ path, ...rest }) => ({
                                  path: Object.keys(props.match.params).length
                                    ? Object.keys(props.match.params)
                                        .reduce((path, param) => path.replace(`:${param}`, props.match.params[param]), path )
                                    : path, ...rest }))

                              return (
                                <>
                                  <BreadCrumbs crumbs={crumbs} />
                                  <Component {...props} />
                                </>
                              );
                           }}
                         />
                     ))}


            </Switch>
         </Router>
```

This is react router V5 technology, and I cannot figure out how to translate this in a context with router V6 (+ Typescript!), where `Route` does not accept a `render(props)` method...
If anyone can see any clearer in this than me, it would be wonderful : )
Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should use `element` and `useParams` inside the component which you pass to `element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `routes` into a routes config so the routed component is passed on the `element` prop. Create a layout route that reads the current `pathname` and string splits it to get each path segment and rebuilds an array of crumbs. `BreadCrumbLayout` renders an `Outlet` for nested routes to render their matched content out to.

Example:

```
const BreadCrumbs = ({ crumbs = [] }) =>
  crumbs.map(({ crumb, label }, i) => (
    <Fragment key={crumb}>
      {i !== 0 && " > "}
      <Link to={crumb}>{label}</Link>
    </Fragment>
  ));

const BreadCrumbLayout = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const crumbs = pathname
    .slice(1)
    .split("/")
    .reduce((crumbs, crumb) => {
      return crumbs.concat({
        crumb: crumbs
          .map(({ crumb }) => crumb)
          .concat(crumb)
          .join("/"),
        label: crumb
      });
    }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <BreadCrumbs crumbs={crumbs} />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

config

```
const routes = [
  {
    element: <BreadCrumbLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: "/home", name: "Home", element: <Home /> },
      { path: "/dashboard", name: "Dashboard", element: <Dashboard /> },
      { path: "/all-users", name: "All users", element: <AllUsers /> },
      { path: "/user/:id", name: "User", element: <User /> },
      {
        path: "/all-contracts",
        name: "All contracts",
        element: <AllContracts />
      },
      { path: "/login", name: "Login", element: <Login /> }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Navigate to="/home" replace />
  }
];
```

Usage:

```
const appRoutes = useRoutes(routes);

...

return (
  <div className="App">
    {appRoutes}
  </div>
);
```

[image]

[image: Edit magical-shockley-qfogov]